# Custom Control Property from DynamicResource

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to combine two concepts, a extending a standard control, and [application theming](https://blog.xamarin.com/easy-app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-styles/) by extending the Picker control and adding in a TextColor property and having a custom renderer on the Android (and iOS eventually) platform. I can successfully set the TextColor property and have it display the color if it is set statically as the following:

```
<controls:ExtendedPicker TextColor="Red"/>
```

The final step in this process is to be able to pull the property from a Dynamic Resource and have it able to be changed at runtime.

```
<controls:ExtendedPicker Style="{DynamicResource pickerStyle}"/>
```

and then, in the Application.Resources ResourceDictionary:

```
<Color x:Key="textColor"/>
...
<Style x:Key="pickerStyle" TargetType="controls:ExtendedPicker">
  <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource textColor}" />
</Style>
```

Note that this method for choosing TextColor works with native controls such as Label. The code compiles and runs but doesn't seem to pick up the dynamic resource color setting when changed at runtime. I am assuming that this is something that I am missing handling this in my custom renderer but am at a loss as to what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle this at run-time I had to override the

```
OnElementPropertyChanged
```

method in the custom renderer rather than the

```
OnElementChanged
```

method.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `OnElementChanged` your custom platform-dependent render and you can get a reference to your `Xamarin.Forms`-based custom (subclassed) control via the `e.NewElement` property.

So you can cast `e.NewElement` as your custom control and get that classes properties (your custom Picker color that you assigned in the XAML):

```
(e.NewElement as ExtendedPicker).TextColor;
```

Something like this:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs< ExtendedPicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if (Control == null) {
           ~~~~~~
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null) {
           ~~~~~~
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            var myPickerControl = (e.NewElement as ExtendedPicker). TextColor;
            // Assign `myPickerControl` to your UI dependent control
            ~~~~~~~
        }
    }
```

Comment: OnElementChanged only appears to occur on creation. When changing it at runtime, I;ve found it only works if I override the OnElementPropertyChanged method.

Comment: Yes, if you want to change the color after initial creation you are correct!, as that would be a prop change, not an element change. Either way, the point is that you have access to your custom color via the event args and just have to assign it to your control as appropriate